# Get HTML response for url specified with #

Tags: html, perl, parsing, anchor

I'm using Perl to gather a list of items spanning multiple pages however the interactive page lists the info by incerementing the value after a # symbol at the end of the page

```
So http://.......#2
then http://.......#3
```

etc.

However I can't get an html response except for the first page.  And even if I open the browser and view page source, safari and firefox only show the first page of results in page source, even if the other pages are shown on screen.

An example of this behavior can be seen at

http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Books-Science-Fiction-Fantasy/zgbs/books/25/ref=zg_bs_nav_b_1_b#4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The information after the `#` mark is not sent to the server. It is used only by client-side code; in this case, there is some JavaScript which renders content dynamically based on the value of the `#` string.

If you want to see that information, you'll need to use a HTTP client that supports JavaScript. I assume you're using something like `LWP` which doesn't.

[WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) is a good choice for remote-controlling a full web browser. It gives you access to the full DOM of the rendered page so you can get dynamic content.